# Powerpoint link to a specific slide

Tags: hyperlink, powerpoint

In Powerpoint, starting from a presentation, it is easy to create a link to a specific slide of another presentation.
I'm trying to figure out how to do the same thing with an external url (for example from a web page).
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Select the text or shape you want to apply the link to, press Ctrl+K (command +K on mac, probably) and choose Existing File in the dialog box that appears. At the bottom of the dialog box, type in the URL of the web page.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Steve, but I would like to do the opposite: from an external file connect to a specific slide.
An example are Onenote linked notes: it is possible to link an Onenote comment with a Powerpoint slide, so I can "jump" from the comment to the slide.
I can't get the link string as a web address (it's definitely not http type ...).
In many posts it is indicated to insert "# slide number" after the file reference but it doesn't work (maybe I'm doing something wrong).

Comment: It seems that the only way to do this is when the PPTX is hosted in OneDrive (or possibly SharePoint).  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/share-a-link-to-a-specific-slide-4f5f3d5e-1674-4742-8cf1-9623050c19ef

Comment: I have seen this possibility. I was wondering if it was possible to replicate it with a local file. Thanks again for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

A VBA macro in Excel can probably do the job for you with local files:

```
Sub JumpToSlide()
    
    Dim oPPT As Object
    Set oPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    
    With oPPT
        .presentations.Open ("C:\temp\test.pptx")
        .ActiveWindow.View.gotoslide (8)
    End With
    
End Sub
```